# SwitchTo for ui-dialog with webdriver c#

Tags: c#, selenium, dialog, selenium-webdriver

The login section of the website i'm testing appears in a dialog that doesn't seem to be a new window pop-up or an alert ( i have tried to SwitchTo()Alert() but it doesn't detect it as Alert; i don't know the name of the iframe or window to switch to it like that as it doesn't seem to be that kind of a dialog).

Is there a way i can switch to something defined like this in order to find the username and password text fields so i can login?

```
   <div class="ui-dialog ui-widget ui-widget-content ui-corner-all ui-draggable" style="display: block; z-index: 1002; outline: 0px none; height: auto; width: auto; top: 181px; left: 304.5px;" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="ui-dialog-title-login-box"></div>
```

Should i rather try finding the elements (username and password) directly with FindElement(By.xpath())?

My code is this:

```
        IWebElement login = driver.FindElement(By.Id("login-button"));
        login.Click();

        WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, TimeSpan.FromSeconds(5));
        wait.Until<bool>((d) =>
        {
            return driver.FindElement(By.Id("username")).Displayed;
        });
        IWebElement username = driver.FindElement(By.Id("username"));

        nickname.SendKeys("some_user");
        IWebElement password = driver.FindElement(By.Id("pass"));
        password.SendKeys("some_password");
```

If i don't wait for the username to be displayed it will show me this:

```
        NoSuchElementException was unhandled: Unable to locate element: {"method":"id", "selector":"username"}.
```

Otherwise the wait times out.

Comment: There should be no "switching" needed. It's not an IFrame, it's not a JavaScript alert (hence `SwitchTo.Alert() didn't work`) and it's a normal DOM element. So what are you having trouble with? What errors do you get?

Comment: If i just search for them like that (driver.FindElement(By.Id("username")); it will throw unhandled exception: 
NoSuchElementException was unhandled: Unable to locate element: {"method":"id", "selector":"username"}. 
But the element is there in the source code, defined like this: <input id="username" class="input-field" type="text" value="" name="username"></input>

Comment: Then it's a different issue. Are you waiting for the element to appear? Have you checked the page source when your test is running?

Comment: Yes, i'm polling the page for 5 sec til the elements are displayed. 
'wait.Until<bool>((d) =>{return username.Displayed;});' But usually when the elements are not loaded it says they're not Visible, not Unable To Locate them.

Comment: No you aren't waiting for it. `username.Displayed` shows you are finding the element *before* the wait. `wait.Until<bool>((d) => {
var element = d.FindElement(By.Id("username"));
return element.Displayed; 
});`

Comment: Yes, i tried that too, it times out after 5 sec without finding anything. i've updated the question with my code.